# Flutter: Hide first alert dialog when other is shown

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-dialog, multiple-alert-dialogs

I want to hide the first alert dialog when I call showDialog() from it. After that when I close the second dialog I want the first dialog was visible again. How I can achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Before you call second dialog, use `Navigator.of(context).pop()` to close first dialog. Then, in the second one, you have functions `then((value) {...})` or `whenComplete(() {...})`, inside that you can use it to re-open first dialog.

That's strange that you want to close first one, why don't you just leave it alone and let the second lies on it?

Comment: I don't want to close the first dialog. I want the second dialog overlapped the first and when I close it, the first dialog will be shown again. I just have added image to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create common dialog to show data. if its already showing then just update data only.

Answer (score 0):

`showDialog` return a future and you can pass data from dialog. The concept is here passing some flag to open the  second dialog.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  final data = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .pop(true); // true for to show second dialog
            },
            child: Text("open Second dialog"),
          ),
        );
      });

  if (data == true) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Second dialog"),
          );
        });
  }
},
```